# LateInitializationError: Field 'prefs' has not been initialized

Tags: initialization, sharedpreferences, preferences

I use sharedpreferences like this

[image]

[image]

---

Why wrong? what initialized..?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please do not upload code/data/error images. Instead copy and paste them using suitable formatting. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

Before using the SharedPreferences variable, you need to initialize it:

```
_prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Then you can use the variable.